# paypal success url error laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, omnipay

I'm using laravel Omni plugin for transactions. Once payment has been done , I'm getting error for success url.

```
public function  checkOut(Request $request)
{
    $params = array(
                'cancelUrl'     => 'http://localhost/vis/public/cancel_order',
                'returnUrl'     => 'http://localhost/vis/public/payment_success',
                'name'      => 'Meal',
                'description'   => 'Casper',
                'amount'    => '1.00',
                'currency'  => 'USD'
            );

    Session::put('params', $params);
    Session::save();
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
    $gateway->setUsername('un');
    $gateway->setPassword('pwd');
    $gateway->setSignature('signature');
    $gateway->setTestMode(true);
    $response = $gateway->purchase($params)->send();

    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        print_r($params);
        redirect('payment_success/' . $this->orderNo);
        // payment was successful: update database
        print_r($response);
    } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {

        // redirect to offsite payment gateway
        $response->redirect();
    } else {
        // payment failed: display message to customer
        echo $response->getMessage();
    }
}

public function getSuccessPayment()
{
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
    $gateway->setUsername('un');
    $gateway->setPassword('pwd');
    $gateway->setSignature('signature');
    $gateway->setTestMode(true);

    $params = Session::get('params');
    $response = $gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();
    $paypalResponse = $response->getData(); // this is the raw response object

    if(isset($paypalResponse['PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK']) && $paypalResponse['PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK'] === 'Success') {
        // Response
        print_r($params);
 //     print_r($paypalResponse);

    } else {

        //Failed transaction

    }
//  return View('result');
    print_r($params);
    print_r($paypalResponse);
}
```

I'm getting following error

> Not Found
>   HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
>   http://localhost/vis/public/payment_success?token=EC-1R845179Asss493N&PayerID=swdw3BS9REA4AN

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have forgotten to add that route in the routes.php, Make sure you have something like this in routes.php

```
Route::get('/payment_success', 'StoreController@getSuccessPayment');
```

Change StoreController to the name of the controller this function is in.